# protobuf-net exception: The type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

The problem is that I don't know all subtypes of base type when model creating and before it will be frozen,    and I don`t want to recreate whole model to extend it with some new subtypes which appears in runtime.
is there any solution?

Comment: The known subtypes get baked in pretty much once a serializer has been generated. And indeed, it is **very** important that you are able to reproduce the right subtypes against the right keys next time it runs. I can have a look if there is more context, but I'm at a conference right now...

Comment: Are you able to add more context here, so I can understand the likely use-cases?